# Is passing password from server to browser in javascript variable over https secure?

Tags: javascript, security, https

Following is our page flow,

1. User is at Login page accessing via https.
2. User enters password and page is submitted (POST method).
3. User credentials is not authenticated now instead server response with some polling page(https).
4. In order to retain the password on poll page, password is passed from server to browser via Javascript variable and onsubmit of poll page, password is passed via POST method. Now server authenticates the user credentials.

Question:
Is passing password from server to browser in javascript variable over https secure?

My opinion

- Entire transaction between the
  browser and server is via https and
  password is passed via POST method -
  so password is SECURE.
- The password is visible via "view
  page source" since it is assigned to
  a javascript variable - NOT SECURE if
  browser plug-in has access to the
  page content. But if browser plug-in
  has access to page content then it
  can even access the password while user enters it, so NO new
  threat is introduced by this flow.

Note

- I know their is better way to handle
  this flow. But I am interested in
  whether our existing flow is secure
  or not.
- Any reference to security tips will
  be helpful.

Comment: And why do you need to send the password back to the browser?

Comment: Consider AJAX, the page wont have to be reloaded and the password wont have to be in the printed in the source code.

Comment: @Jared Because in this flow the authorization is happening in 2nd step i.e after submitting the polling page. Actually I was suggesting to improve the current flow to my team. But they are postponing because of NO security threat. So I posted this question to make sure this flow has NO security threat.

Comment: Just as easy to hash it and check that against the database when you need to (or to hash and hash with salt for the browser, then check that against the stored hash with salt value in the database). You are hashing the password values in the database, correct? They aren't plaintext?

Comment: I just don't see the need to send the value back to the user. It should only be transitory when they submit in plaintext, then hashed (at least sha1) for the longterm storage, and check against that hash as necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bigger issue is best practice - you just don't need to do it, and it's bad practice. This would indicate a poor understanding of security overall - it's a best practice to not store the password in plaintext ever. If your programmer coworkers do not give proper credence to this concept, then I would suggest they may have other areas they are lax in observing, security-wise.

[Security is a mindset](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2008/03/the_security_mi_1.html), not a lowest common denominator. It's about giving as few opportunities for compromise as possible, giving as little wedge room as possible.

Not storing plaintext passwords is what you should do, not "store them when we want unless someone can prove it's bad".

> This interest in "harmless failures" –
> cases where an adversary can cause an
> anomalous but not directly harmful
> outcome – is another hallmark of the
> security mindset. Not all "harmless
> failures" lead to big trouble, but
> **it's surprising how often a clever
> adversary can pile up a stack of
> seemingly harmless failures into a
> dangerous tower of trouble**. Harmless
> failures are bad hygiene. We try to
> stamp them out when we can.

http://freedom-to-tinker.com/blog/felten/security-mindset-and-harmless-failures

Comment: It always make me cringe when a website sends my plaintext password to me in an email, or prints it on the screen. Sure, it's a pain to go through a challenge-response to reset, but it's at least possible for it to be more secure.

Answer (score 0):

The transmission would be secure. But it would be inadvisable to send it with a response because browsers would cache the value with the page. Someone could maliciously view source of the page and view the password.

Could you do this by passing a server session key?

Comment: Yes. I checked about:cache in FF and https link also cached by FF. But the content is in encoded state along with "security-info" variable, hope with this variable we can decode the page content [But I am not sure how to decode]. Anyway we are in trouble :( Good part is we know the cause :)

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the transactions themselves may be secure from some forms of interception, but you're opening yourself up to a number of other attacks that don't rely on intercepting the request/response activity. What if some page of your site is susceptible to cross side scripting and some malicious javascript gets on your page?

Comment: Yep, Cross site scripting will be an issue. As Daniel suggested browser-cache is another threat. Let me fix this flow ASAP :)